# storing input into variable

Tags: iphone

Hi I am seeking some insight into storing text input into a variable. My task is to take five text inputs, store the numbers the user inputs, then do some fancy math with them to create a solution variable to display. However, within the SDK I am getting confused quickly on how to actually store these correctly. I can't find much tutorials on this online, seeking gurus to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward stuff.

Declare the variable:

```
 NSString *aString;
```

Then assign the string:

```
aString = someTextField.text;
```

If you're going to need the string to stick around for any period of time beyond the method where you capture it, you might consider making it a property of the class:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;
```

That's just for a string. If the user is inputting text that you want to treat as a number, you can do:

```
NSInteger userInputInteger = [someTextField.text intValue];
```

Comment: TY Danilo. I really appreciate your help. I'm going to muck around with this and see what I can break :)

Comment: You got it! Good luck. The docs in Xcode are pretty thorough. Very useful once you learn to get around in them. A quick read through the Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language guide and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague… depending on what you want to do there are many ways:

- **Temporary storage**.  Set up a NSString variable to hold the input, then do whatever you need to do to validate/convert etc

`NSString *input1 = textField.text;`

- **Storage Over one run of the app**.  Setup a global variable in a custom class, model, or view controller that will not be dealloc'ed

`[MyStorageClass setInput1:textField.text];`

- **Save over multiple launches of the app**. Put the vars in NSUserDefaults

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"input1"];`

Comment: sorry. store the input into a variable that will be used only during run of app